# Accidentaly rm -rf / from different OS

Tags: linux, boot, arch-linux

I have 2 arch linux installed, one primary and the other secondary. I had mounted the primary onto the second at `/mnt/sda2` (`/dev/sda2` being my primary OS) and then did `umount /mnt/sda2` but didn’t notice the message saying “disk is busy”, and as I thought it was unmounted I did `rm -rf /mnt/sda2`. It was taking a while so I understood I messed up, so I Ctrl-C’d immediately. But within a few seconds it broke my primary system.

So I tried a couple of things, I booted an iso (arch linux latest) and copied `/usr/bin` as it was completely missing. And I copied over `/usr/lib/*` from the iso over to the primary partition because I tried pacstrapping `base linux-lts linux-firmware` but some `libc.so.6` and several other similar files were missing so the pacstrap didn’t complete. So only after copying the libc files was I able to chroot and do pacstrap.

Now even after copying when I tried pacstrap, everything goes smoothly until an error message comes:

> call to execv failed (No such file or directory)
> failed to execute program

And also I tried chrooting and installing them (the base packages) using `pacman` that too gives the same error and also one more error I noticed was

> could not open /sys/devices/system/cpu/microcode/reload (read-only file system)

Grub is not affected at all I think, grub works fine but when I try to boot now, it gets stuck on

> Loading kernel linux-lts …
> Loading inital ramdisk …
> _

Previously some other errors were shown like `/sbin/init` (no such file or directory) and thats when I copied from iso. And it also used to jump into a CLI with `[rootfs]:` promot.

Answer (score 0):

Your Linux system is missing essential files. You should really
give up and take the easy way out by reinstalling Linux.

While booting the Live USB, after selecting all the options,
you might be lucky and get in the "Installation Type" screen the
option of "Reinstall Ubuntu" (or your distribution).
This option will keep your existing data and even tries to keep the
installed software. If you see this option, you have struck gold.

Otherwise, the remaining option is "Erase Ubuntu and reinstall",
meaning that you start from scratch.

If you were using separate partitions for root and home, you can keep
your data in the home partition safe even if you reinstall Linux
(see the link below).

In any case, you should use the Live USB to take a backup of your
data before doing these manipulations.

For more information, see for example this tutorial:
[How to Reinstall Ubuntu in Dual Boot or Single Boot Mode](https://itsfoss.com/reinstall-ubuntu/).